# Group by multiple tables to List

Tags: c#, linq

I have 4 tables

```
     - User
        - UserId
        - UserName

     - Device
        - DeviceId
        - DeviceTypeId (FK DeviceType)

     - DeviceType  
        - DeviceTypeId

     - UserDevice  
       - UserId (FK User)
       - DeviceId (FK Device)
```

I would like to get list of devices that 1 user has, grouped by DeviceType. So result class should be something like this

```
class m
{
   int DeviceTypeId;
   List<Device> devices;
}
```

I did try few tricks in LINQ but didnt get desired result. It has been years since I used LINQ last time.

Comment: years? ... well what have you tried today?

Comment: Got here, but I am stuck now

 from d in db.Devices
                    join dt in db.DeviceType on d.DeviceTypeId equals dt.DeviceTypeId
                    join du in db.UserDevices on d.DeviceId equals du.DeviceId
                    where (du.UserId == currentuser)
                    group new {d, dt} by new {d.DeviceId, dt.DeviceTypeId}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with your comment:

```
var data = from d in db.Devices 
           join dt in db.DeviceType on d.DeviceTypeId equals dt.DeviceTypeId 
           join du in db.UserDevices on d.DeviceId equals du.DeviceId 
           where (du.UserId == currentUser) 
           group d by d into g
           select new m 
           { 
               DeviceTypeId = g.Key.DeviceTypeId, 
               devices = (from d in g select d).ToList()
           };
```

If you add `public string TypeName { get; set; }` to your `m` class, you can populate it with this query:

```
var data = from d in devices 
           join dt in deviceTypes on d.DeviceTypeId equals dt.DeviceTypeId 
           join du in userDevices on d.DeviceId equals du.DeviceId 
           where (du.UserId == 1) 
           group d by dt into g
           select new m
           {
               DeviceTypeId = g.Key.DeviceTypeId, 
               TypeName = g.Key.TypeName,
               devices = (from d in g select d).ToList()
           };
```

Comment: Just as you anwserd I managed to solve it :) 1 more question. If I add TypeName to DeviceType table, how can replace ID from  class m with that? Tnx!

I replaced g.Key.DeviceTypeId with g.Key.DeviceType.DeviceTypeName. Is this Ok?

Comment: @LukaPivk I've updated my answer to include `TypeName`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

```
return 
   userDevices
   .Where(ud => ud.UserId == myUserId)
   .SelectMany(ud => devices.Where(d => d.DeviceId == ud.DeviceId))
   .GroupBy(d => d.DeviceTypeId)
   .Select(g => new m { DeviceTypeId = g.Key, devices = g.ToList() });
```

of course I cannot test this but it should be about right (minus some spelling problems)

BTW: I did not even try to give you some ORM like syntax as I have no clue what you are using here - this might be a rather poor performing solution but you should get the idea ...

Comment: yes sorry - should be `g.ToList()` (as I said - minus spelling ;) )